# Why can't I use textTheme inside Column's Text widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, material3

I have customTheme which has

```
import 'package:app/core/util/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class CustomTheme {
  static getTheme() {
    return ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.interTextTheme(
          const TextTheme(
            displayLarge:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 57, letterSpacing: 0.25, height: 64),
          ),
        ),
        primaryColor: AppConstants.gold,
        useMaterial3: true);
  }
}
```

main code is like this

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: CustomTheme.getTheme(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const OnBoardingPage());
  }
}
```

and now I have onboardingpage which has column inside there is text which uses displaylarge.
this guy is causing problem.

```
  const OnBoardingPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Text("Imagination Meets Intelligence",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error is

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 2890 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Column
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,

What did I try ?

- I tried wrapping inside Expanded,
- I tried changing the column into listview.

nothing is working why ??????

Comment: Text is too big for the column.  Make it a ListView (which is a column plus a scroll)

Comment: Actually no, i am trying it in chrome, so that shouldn't be a problem and I tried your solution error vanishes however my text is not displayed at all

Comment: Place a SingleChildScrollView on top of the Column. Ex:
```SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(children:[Text('text large here')]))```